# javascript NaN variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, nan

I'm doing some kind of quiz and counting the good results, but on the last one, my variable gets `NaN` and I don't know why. Anyone has a clue?

Every alert is counting well: 1, 2, 3, 4 but on `.gotoresult` it always gives `NaN` in the alert, so it always goes to .lost.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var success = 0;
  $('.gotostep1').on('click', function() {
    success = 0;
    if ($(this).attr('correct') == 'true') {
      success++;
    }
    alert(success);
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $('.step1').show();
  });
  $('.gotostep2').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('correct') == 'true') {
      success++;
    }
    alert(success);
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
    $('.step2').show();
  });
  $('.gotostep3').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('correct') == 'true') {
      success++;
    }
    alert(success);
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
    $('.step3').show();
  });
  $('.gotostep4').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('correct') == 'true') {
      success++;
    }
    alert(success);
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
    $('.step4').show();
  });
  $('.gotostep5').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('correct') == 'true') {
      success++;
    }
    alert(success);
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
    $('.step5').show();
  });
  $('.gotoresult').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('correct') == 'true') {
      success++;
    }
    alert(success);
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
    if (success == 5) {
      $('.won').show();
    } else {
      var success = true;
      $('.lost').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="step intro">
  <button class="gotostep1">Start de quiz</button>
</div>
<div class="step step1" style="display:none;">
  <h3 class="contentTitle">Vraag 1</h3>
  <div class="img-selection-container">
    <div class="img-left img-semi">
      <img class="gotostep2" correct="false" src="/static/media/vraag1a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-right img-semi">
      <img class="gotostep2" correct="true" src="/static/media/vraag1b.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="step step2" style="display:none;">
  <h3 class="contentTitle">Vraag 2</h3>
  <div class="img-selection-container">
    <div class="img-left img-semi">
      <img class="gotostep3" correct="true" src="/static/media/vraag2a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-right img-semi">
      <img class="gotostep3" correct="false" src="/static/media/vraag2b.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="step step3" style="display:none;">
  <h3 class="contentTitle">Vraag 3</h3>
  <div class="img-selection-container">
    <div class="img-left img-semi">
      <img class="gotostep4" correct="false" src="/static/media/vraag3a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-right img-semi">
      <img class="gotostep4" correct="true" src="/static/media/vraag3b.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="step step4" style="display:none;">
  <h3 class="contentTitle">Vraag 4</h3>
  <div class="img-selection-container">
    <div class="img-left img-semi">
      <img class="gotostep5" correct="true" src="/static/media/vraag4a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-right img-semi">
      <img class="gotostep5" correct="false" src="/static/media/vraag4b.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="step step5" style="display:none;">
  <h3 class="contentTitle">Strikvraag</h3>
  <div class="img-selection-container">
    <div class="img-left img-semi">
      <img class="gotoresult" correct="true" src="/static/media/vraag5a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-right img-semi">
      <img class="gotoresult" correct="false" src="/static/media/vraag5b.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="step lost" style="display:none;">
  lost!
</div>
<div class="step won" style="display:none;">
  won!
</div>
```

Comment: Side note:  you might want to consider using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) instead of your custom "correct" attribute.

Comment: You should highly consider writing that code to be less specific.  As it is, it's hard to debug and very not [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: It's likely at some point you add something to something else that isn't an actual number. It's also not clear which `success` you're referring two when, because you have at least two declarations, one of which hides the other.

Comment: It seems to be `var success = true;` that does the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare success again inside  $('.gotoresult') onclick event, making the type from integer to boolean, which cause the NAN error.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var success = 0;
  $('.gotostep1').on('click', function() {
    success = 0;
    if ($(this).attr('correct') == 'true') {
      success++;
    }
    alert(success);
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $('.step1').show();
  });
  $('.gotostep2').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('correct') == 'true') {
      success++;
    }
    alert(success);
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
    $('.step2').show();
  });
  $('.gotostep3').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('correct') == 'true') {
      success++;
    }
    alert(success);
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
    $('.step3').show();
  });
  $('.gotostep4').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('correct') == 'true') {
      success++;
    }
    alert(success);
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
    $('.step4').show();
  });
  $('.gotostep5').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('correct') == 'true') {
      success++;
    }
    alert(success);
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
    $('.step5').show();
  });
  $('.gotoresult').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('correct') == 'true') {
      success++;
    }
    alert(success);
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
    if (success == 5) {
      $('.won').show();
    } else {
      success = 0;
      $('.lost').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="step intro">
  <button class="gotostep1">Start de quiz</button>
</div>
<div class="step step1" style="display:none;">
  <h3 class="contentTitle">Vraag 1</h3>
  <div class="img-selection-container">
    <div class="img-left img-semi">
      <img class="gotostep2" correct="false" src="/static/media/vraag1a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-right img-semi">
      <img class="gotostep2" correct="true" src="/static/media/vraag1b.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="step step2" style="display:none;">
  <h3 class="contentTitle">Vraag 2</h3>
  <div class="img-selection-container">
    <div class="img-left img-semi">
      <img class="gotostep3" correct="true" src="/static/media/vraag2a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-right img-semi">
      <img class="gotostep3" correct="false" src="/static/media/vraag2b.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="step step3" style="display:none;">
  <h3 class="contentTitle">Vraag 3</h3>
  <div class="img-selection-container">
    <div class="img-left img-semi">
      <img class="gotostep4" correct="false" src="/static/media/vraag3a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-right img-semi">
      <img class="gotostep4" correct="true" src="/static/media/vraag3b.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="step step4" style="display:none;">
  <h3 class="contentTitle">Vraag 4</h3>
  <div class="img-selection-container">
    <div class="img-left img-semi">
      <img class="gotostep5" correct="true" src="/static/media/vraag4a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-right img-semi">
      <img class="gotostep5" correct="false" src="/static/media/vraag4b.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="step step5" style="display:none;">
  <h3 class="contentTitle">Strikvraag</h3>
  <div class="img-selection-container">
    <div class="img-left img-semi">
      <img class="gotoresult" correct="true" src="/static/media/vraag5a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-right img-semi">
      <img class="gotoresult" correct="false" src="/static/media/vraag5b.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="step lost" style="display:none;">
  lost!
</div>
<div class="step won" style="display:none;">
  won!
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The secret is not to use counted CSS classes.

Look how short the code gets when all items that *are* the same (like all questions) also have the same CSS class.

```js
$(function() {
  var success = 0;

  // every answer reveals the next answer
  $('.answer').click(function () {
    if ($(this).data('correct')) success++;
    $(this).closest('.question').hide().next('.question').show();
  });

  // the last answer reveals the overall result
  $('.question:last() .answer').click(function () {
    var result = (success == $('.answer').length) ? '#won' : '#lost';
    $(result).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.question, .result {
  display: none;
}
.question.intro {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="question intro">
  <button class="answer">Start de quiz</button>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <h3 class="contentTitle">Vraag 1</h3>
  <div class="img-selection-container">
    <div class="img-left img-semi">
      <img class="answer" data-correct="false" src="/static/media/vraag1a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-right img-semi">
      <img class="answer" data-correct="true" src="/static/media/vraag1b.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <h3 class="contentTitle">Vraag 2</h3>
  <div class="img-selection-container">
    <div class="img-left img-semi">
      <img class="answer" data-correct="true" src="/static/media/vraag2a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-right img-semi">
      <img class="answer" data-correct="false" src="/static/media/vraag2b.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <h3 class="contentTitle">Vraag 3</h3>
  <div class="img-selection-container">
    <div class="img-left img-semi">
      <img class="answer" data-correct="false" src="/static/media/vraag3a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-right img-semi">
      <img class="answer" data-correct="true" src="/static/media/vraag3b.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <h3 class="contentTitle">Vraag 4</h3>
  <div class="img-selection-container">
    <div class="img-left img-semi">
      <img class="answer" data-correct="true" src="/static/media/vraag4a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-right img-semi">
      <img class="answer" data-correct="false" src="/static/media/vraag4b.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <h3 class="contentTitle">Strikvraag</h3>
  <div class="img-selection-container">
    <div class="img-left img-semi">
      <img class="answer" data-correct="true" src="/static/media/vraag5a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-right img-semi">
      <img class="answer" data-correct="false" src="/static/media/vraag5b.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="result" id="lost">lost!</div>
<div class="result" id="won">won!</div>
```